# Auth::check() false even if logged in

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

if the email and username is incorrect it redirects to `/login`. And if i am successfully logged in, it donot redirect to `/crud`.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
            $password=$request->get('password');
            $email=$request->get('email');
            if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]) )
            {           
                return redirect()->intended('/crud');   
            }
            else 
            {
                return redirect('/crud/login');
            }
    }
```

but then again if i am logged in this function below shows me  logged in.

```
public function check()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) 
        {
            print_r('logged in');
        }
        else
        {
            print_r('not logged in');
        }
    }
```

this is how i protected `/crud`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','web']], function () {
    Route::get('/crud','CrudController@index');
});
```

Comment: Why are you changing the built in `authenticate` method?

Comment: I have not changed. Just used manaul authentication.

Comment: this exact functionality is built-in the framework by default.

Comment: post your routes file